# get-azpolicysetdefinition 'view definition'

Tags: azure-policy

In the portal when you view a policy initiative there is a button for 'view definition'. Where can we access this information in powershell?

get-azpolicysetdefinition returns the policies assigned but not the root definition.

get-azpolicysetdefinition -custom
get-azpolicydefinition -custom

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Get-AzPolicyDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azpolicydefinition?view=azps-9.2.0) to retrieve the information related to policy definition.To get entire definition, you need to drill down through the command as shown below.

```
(Get-AzPolicyDefinition -ID /providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/b4fe1a3b-0715-4c6c-a5ea-ffc33cf823cb).Properties
```

[image: snapshot of output]

```
(Get-AzPolicyDefinition -ID /providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/b4fe1a3b-0715-4c6c-a5ea-ffc33cf823cb).Properties.PolicyRule
```

[image: snapshot of output]

```
((Get-AzPolicyDefinition -ID /providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/b4fe1a3b-0715-4c6c-a5ea-ffc33cf823cb).Properties.PolicyRule).then
```

[image: snapshot of output]